# JSplitPane Maximum size for bottom part

Tags: height, max, resizable, jsplitpane

Is it possible to set the maximum height of the bottom part of a JSplitPane ? I don't want it to be resizable too much.

How to do this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

JSplitPane has 2 method: .setDividerLocation(int pixels) and .setDividerLocation(double percents). Code will be easy:

```
jSplitPane.setDividerLocation(0.0); // set maximum height of the bottom part
```